# Need to accept shutdown instructions over a socket connection

Tags: python, network-programming

I have created a connection from client to server over a socket on specified port. Client and server can communicate just fine. Wanna be able to shutdown client from server. I have the following code:

```
def handle_client(client_socket):

    query = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print ("Received the following: %s") % query

if query == 'shutdown':
   os.system("shutdown now -h") #shutdown host

else:
   client_socket.close() #shuts down client
```

I run this and I get the error that query is not defined.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must define query as a global variable so it can be accessed outside of the function "handle_client". Do this by:

```
def handle_client(client_socket):
    global query ##define it as a global variable

    query = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print ("Received the following: %s" %(query)) ##also, the % operator needs to be inside the print statement

if query == 'shutdown':
   os.system("shutdown now -h")

else:
   client_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your indentation. as you know python is sensitive to indentation.

it must be like this:

```
def handle_client(client_socket):

    query = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print ("Received the following: %s") % query

    if query == 'shutdown':
        os.system("shutdown now -h") #shutdown host
    else:
        client_socket.close() #shuts down client
```